# Mathdesign and listings packages result in bitmap fonts

Tags: listings, mathdesign

When using the `listings` package to display code together with `mathdesign`, it seems that a bitmap font is used. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}
%\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize, frame=single, tabsize=4}

\begin{document}
Some text to describe my function
\lstinputlisting[language=Python]{script.py}
\end{document}
```

This file procuces an output where "Some text to describe my function" is displayed correctly (in Adobe Reader) while the code is pixelated. If I use the `lmodern` package instead, the code looks fine. It also works correctly when omitting the `ttfamily` setting in `lstset`.

Is it possible to display the code in vector format with my choice of fonts?

Comment: install the cm-super package.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in a comment, I installed the `cm-super` package, but it was not enough to solve the problem. It is also necessary to load the `lmodern` package in the preamble, just before `mathdesign`:

```
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}

\usepackage{listings}
```

With this configuration, the pdf output is as expected!

Comment: Are you using MiKTeX, by chance?

Comment: Yes, I am using the latest version (2.9.6615).

Comment: Well, MiKTeX is known not to always update the font maps. Look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108447/